# What is the shortest one-liner to divide the line count of one file by another in bash?

Tags: bash, division, wc

In a bash shell, I am trying to write a short one-liner to divide the line count of one file by the line count of another. I would like show at least two decimal places from floating-point division.

In other words, I would like a one-liner to print the percentage of one file's line count of another.

For example, if I have a first file (first.txt) with 25 lines and a second file (second.txt) with 100 lines, the one-liner would output `.25`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some test material:

```
$ for i in {1..25} ; do echo $i >> first ; done
$ for i in {1..100} ; do echo $i >> second ; done
```

Then some awk:

```
$ awk 'END{print(NR-FNR)/FNR}' first second
0.25
```

`NR` is the total number of records in both files. At the `END` `FNR`is the number of records in the latter file, so `(NR-FNR)/FNR` is the record count of the first file divided by the record count of the second.

Other than the solutions provided here, you need to take your question to [the code golf course](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) .

Answer (score 3):

The shortest I could come up with made use of *command substitution* and *redirection*

```
$ echo "scale=2; $(wc -l <first.txt) / $(wc -l <second.txt)" | bc
.25
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you could use `gawk` as:

```
gawk 'NR==FNR{a+=1;next} {b+=1} END{printf "%.2f\n", a/b}' first.txt second.txt
```

Comment: This is great as it makes it easy to swap out the file parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following stores the line counts of the two files in two variables. The filenames and leading whitespace are removed from the output of `wc` using `sed` and `cut`. The division is then performed on the two variables using `bc`.

```
count1=$(wc -l first.txt | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' | cut -f 1 -d ' ') && count2=$(wc -l second.txt | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' | cut -f 1 -d ' ') && echo "scale=2; $count1/$count2" | bc
```

Comment: If you **redirect** the file's contents into `wc`, you don't have to parse out the filename. See David C. Rankin's answer

Answer (score 0):

Shortest version using `bc` and `grep`

```
echo "$(grep -c '$' file1) / $(grep -c '$' file2)" | bc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate GNU awk answer, using a bunch of builtin variables
:

```
gawk '
    ENDFILE {nr[FILENAME] = FNR} 
    END {printf "%.2f\n", nr[ARGV[1]] / nr[ARGV[2]]}
' first.txt second.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One time use

```
echo `wc -l <first.txt`/`wc -l <second.txt`|bc -l
```

One script use

```
e(){ echo `wc -l <$1`/`wc -l <$2` | bc -l;}
e first.txt second.txt
```

One user use: add function to .bashrc

Everyone use: add function to /etc/bash.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

```
bash-4.4$ a=$(perl -e "print $(cat file1|wc -l) /$(cat file2|wc -l)")                                                                                                                   
bash-4.4$ echo $a                                                                                                                                                                   
0.333333333333333
```

Edited the answer to support decimal values

Comment: Why the `echo` when `expr` already prints the desired result?

Comment: edited the answer to use perl -e . This should probably work now

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to all the `bc` answers:

```
dc <<< "2k $(wc -l < file1) $(wc -l < file2) /p"
```

The `2k` sets the precision, here the output will always have two decimal places.